# Hyphen separated string from hashmap keyset

Tags: java, string, hashmap

I have keyset in which keys are product name, I want to accumulate all the product name in single String variable in below format:

Prod1-Prod2-Prod3

I have tried

```
for(String prod: map.keySet()){
String prodName+=prod+"-";
}
```

but it displays

```
nullProd1-Prod2-
```

How do I get rid of `null` and the last extra hyphen

Comment: Easiest is to use `String.join("-", map.keySet())`.

Comment: Wow.......it works like a charm, thanks so much